# How do I fix the circular import in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to simply put a 'Hello World' text on the server. And it brings an error.

**Project Urls.py** :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

**App Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpattern = [
    path('', views.index,name = 'index')
]
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(response):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello World</h1>')
```

**The Error it tells me:**
The included URLconf in myapp/urls.py does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an 's' in your apps urls.py.
it has to be '`urlpatterns`', instead of '`urlpattern`'

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name = 'index')
]
```